# Parse Cisco interfaces using regex/python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse information from the output of multiple interfaces from a Cisco router. My goal is a dictionary where i can use named regex captures to pull out required information.

I have tried using predefined sub patterns using the [Python PyPi *regex* module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) but am having issues getting multiple named captures per match. Ideally, i would like to have all items captured to a single match per interface:

```
Match 1:
Interface: x/x/x/1
MTU: 1234
BIA: x.x.x.1

Match 2:
Interface: x/x/x/2
MTU: 4321
BIA: x.x.x.2
```

And so on for every interface i have in my output.

Here is my regex that i have so far, its working great until i try to capture any additional output. Once i add regex to match other items (ie. MTU) i no longer get any matches. What am I missing?

```
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<intfs>)
        (?<mtus>)
        (?<end>^$|\Z)
    )
    ^(?P<intf>(?&intfs)[Gig|Ten|Hun]\S+)
    MTU\ (?P<mtu>\d+)(?&mtus)
    (?P<misc>(?!^$)[\s\S]+?)
    (?&end)
```

**Test string:**

```
    TenGigE0/1/0/0 is up, line protocol is up
      Interface state transitions: 7
      Hardware is TenGigE, address is 0026.982f.6fc0 (bia 0026.982f.6fc0)
      Layer 1 Transport Mode is LAN
      Description: LAB1
      Internet address is 172.25.26.1/31
      MTU 9172 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit (Max: 10000000 Kbit)
         reliability 255/255, txload 62/255, rxload 192/255

    HundredGigE0/1/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
      Interface state transitions: 1
      Hardware is TenGigE, address is 0026.982f.6fc1 (bia 0026.982f.6fc1)
      Layer 1 Transport Mode is LAN
      Description: LAB2
      Internet address is 172.25.25.1/31
      MTU 9192 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit (Max: 10000000 Kbit)
         reliability 255/255, txload 150/255, rxload 20/255
```

**Goal:**

```
    {'interfaces': {'HundredGigE0/1/0/1': {'IP Address': '172.25.25.1/31',
                                           'MTU': '9192',
                                           'bia': '0026.982f.6fc1'},
                    'TenGigE0/1/0/0': {'IP Address': '172.25.26.1/31',
                                       'MTU': '9172',
                                       'bia': '0026.982f.6fc0'}}}
```

Comment: The regex you have is incompatible with `re`. I also believe you wanted to use `(Gig|Ten|Hun)` instead of `[Gig|Ten|Hun]` (if you plan to match `Gig`, `Ten` or `Hun` substrings).

Comment: I am using the regex module not the re module.

Comment: At any rate, your pattern is incomplete since the DEFINE block contains empty named groups, and the code where you use the regex is missing.

Comment: `[Gig|Ten|Hun]` is equivalent to `[GgHienTu|]`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I will play around with it more, first time working with DEFINE blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to solve your problem in Python PyPi regex module but here is the solution using re module. I think it might help you.

```
import re
testString="""    TenGigE0/1/0/0 is up, line protocol is up
      Interface state transitions: 7
      Hardware is TenGigE, address is 0026.982f.6fc0 (bia 0026.982f.6fc0)
      Layer 1 Transport Mode is LAN
      Description: LAB1
      Internet address is 172.25.26.1/31
      MTU 9172 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit (Max: 10000000 Kbit)
         reliability 255/255, txload 62/255, rxload 192/255

    HundredGigE0/1/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
      Interface state transitions: 1
      Hardware is TenGigE, address is 0026.982f.6fc1 (bia 0026.982f.6fc1)
      Layer 1 Transport Mode is LAN
      Description: LAB2
      Internet address is 172.25.25.1/31
      MTU 9192 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit (Max: 10000000 Kbit)
         reliability 255/255, txload 150/255, rxload 20/255"""

#print(testString)
#matchobj=re.search(r"(?P<intrfname>[A-Za-z]+[01]/[01]/[01]/[01]).*?\(bia (?P<bia>[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4})\).*?Internet address is (?P<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/\d\d{1,5}).*?MTU (?P<mtu>[0-9]+ )",testString,re.M|re.DOTALL)
#if matchobj:
        #print( "\n\nHERE IT IS :: \nInterface : " + matchobj.group('intrfname')  + "\n\nBIA : " + matchobj.group('bia')+ "\n\nIP Address : " +  matchobj.group('ipaddr') + "\n\nMTU : " + matchobj.group('mtu') + "\n\n"+ matchobj.group())

interfaces=re.findall(r"(?P<intrfname>[A-Za-z]+[01]/[01]/[01]/[01]).*?\(bia (?P<bia>[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4})\).*?Internet address is (?P<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/\d\d{1,5}).*?MTU (?P<mtu>[0-9]+ )",testString,re.M|re.DOTALL)
#print(interfaces)
result={"interfaces":{}}
#print(result)
for interface in interfaces:
        interfaceName=interface[0]
        result["interfaces"][interfaceName]={}
        result["interfaces"][interfaceName]["IP Address"]=interface[2]
        result["interfaces"][interfaceName]["MTU"]=interface[3]
        result["interfaces"][interfaceName]["bia"]=interface[1]

print(result)
```

**Output :**

```
{'interfaces': {'TenGigE0/1/0/0': {'IP Address': '172.25.26.1/31', 'MTU': '9172 ', 'bia': '0026.982f.6fc0'}, 'HundredGigE0/1/0/1': {'IP Address': '172.25.25.1/31', 'MTU': '9192 ', 'bia': '0026.982f.6fc1'}}}
```

Remove the above comments for better understanding of the code. Comment below if you have any doubt about the code.